# Setting the BaseX Document/Database context programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, basex

I am attempting to set the database/document context programmatically via the Python API. My steps are as follows:

```
session = BaseXClient.Session("localhost", 1984, "admin", "admin")
query = session.query("//node")
query.context("doc('dbname')") # **NOT SURE HOW TO SET THE DB TO USE**
query.execute()
```

I already know that I can simply use the session object as follows and it works fine:

```
session.execute("xquery doc('dbname')//node/child")
```

But I am looking for a way to OPEN a database within the scope of the program call separate from the query string. I am not able to find the documentation to explicitly set the database prior to executing the query using the context object. I have looked at the source code for the python [BaseXClient](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/blob/master/basex-api/src/main/python/BaseXClient/BaseXClient.py) and there is context method for the Query() instance that is not well documented. I am attempting to use this to set the Database and not having much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context you have supplied is just a string. It is not evaluated. In a client server context it is difficult to see how one could pass in a database here.

I think your alternatives are to use the `execute` command to open a database before running the query. This will set the context. e.g.

```
var q = session.execute("open mydatabase",log.print)
var q = session.query("count(*)")
```

or use the query command `bind` command to pass parameters

```
var q = session.query("declare variable $db external;  count(collection($db))")
q.bind("db", "mydatabase","",log.print);
q.execute(log.print);
```

Sorry these examples use Javascript and my [BaseX Node client](https://github.com/apb2006/basex-node)  as I am not familiar with the Python API but I am sure the same applies in the Python API

Comment: Thanks Andy! I ended using session.execute("open mydatabase") before calling the query.